# Superclass for different branches

Tags: java, spring, class, inheritance

I have a Spring web application with some branches/projects that are integrated to it. Two of them have similar superclasses and i want to avoid extra code. Is there a way of having those superclasses for this two separate branches/projects in one place? I'm trying to avoid merging them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Extract the common superclass into a separate, shared module (jar) and use it in both projects.